# How to Store Tweets in HDFS?

Tags: twitter, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, flume

How to Store particular website tweets in HDFS ?

Suppose one website www.abcd.com  and I want to collect all user's tweet for this website and stored into HDFS or Hive.

Flume and sqoop also helpful for storing data.

so anyone please suggest me how flume and sqoop work in storing tweets in HDFS?

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop was not made for this purpose. Flume is used for these kind of needs. You can write your custom Flume source that will pull the tweets and dump them into your HDFS. See **[this](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/10/analyzing-twitter-data-with-hadoop-part-2-gathering-data-with-flume/)** for example. It shows how to use Flume to collect data from the Twitter Streaming API, and forward it to HDFS.

You can find more in the **[official documentation](http://flume.apache.org/documentation.html)**.